# Find and Check a Checkbox without ID and Submit Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, checkbox

I'm trying to check a few checkboxes, add data to a form, and submit it. I've been able to fill out the text fields and select widgets, but the checkbox seems to be another problem. Here is the HTML code of one of the checkboxes:

```
<fieldset class="s-lc-rm-cap-l-1"><legend><h2>IVC Library - Room 100E <small>Capacity: 1</small></h2></legend><div>Location: First floor

Room amenities: 
- one table, four chairs
- a white board*
- a tower fan

*Markers are available for checkout at the Circulation Desk</div><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796847">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796847" value="489796847" data-seq="2281101" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796847');">
                        8:00am - 8:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796847" id="sch489796847dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796847" id="t_sch489796847" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:00am - 8:30am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796848">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796848" value="489796848" data-seq="2281102" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796848');">
                        8:30am - 9:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796848" id="sch489796848dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796848" id="t_sch489796848" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 8:30am - 9:00am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796849">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796849" value="489796849" data-seq="2281103" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796849');">
                        9:00am - 9:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796849" id="sch489796849dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796849" id="t_sch489796849" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 9:00am - 9:30am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796850">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796850" value="489796850" data-seq="2281104" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796850');">
                        9:30am - 10:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796850" id="sch489796850dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796850" id="t_sch489796850" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 9:30am - 10:00am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796851">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796851" value="489796851" data-seq="2281105" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796851');">
                        10:00am - 10:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796851" id="sch489796851dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796851" id="t_sch489796851" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 10:00am - 10:30am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796852">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796852" value="489796852" data-seq="2281106" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796852');">
                        10:30am - 11:00am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796852" id="sch489796852dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796852" id="t_sch489796852" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 10:30am - 11:00am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796853">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796853" value="489796853" data-seq="2281107" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796853');">
                        11:00am - 11:30am
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796853" id="sch489796853dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796853" id="t_sch489796853" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 11:00am - 11:30am Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796854">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796854" value="489796854" data-seq="2281108" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796854');">
                        11:30am - 12:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796854" id="sch489796854dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796854" id="t_sch489796854" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 11:30am - 12:00pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796855">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796855" value="489796855" data-seq="2281109" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796855');">
                        12:00pm - 12:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796855" id="sch489796855dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796855" id="t_sch489796855" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 12:00pm - 12:30pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796856">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796856" value="489796856" data-seq="2281110" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796856');">
                        12:30pm - 1:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796856" id="sch489796856dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796856" id="t_sch489796856" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 12:30pm - 1:00pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796857">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796857" value="489796857" data-seq="2281111" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796857');">
                        1:00pm - 1:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796857" id="sch489796857dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796857" id="t_sch489796857" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 1:00pm - 1:30pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796858">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796858" value="489796858" data-seq="2281112" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796858');">
                        1:30pm - 2:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796858" id="sch489796858dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796858" id="t_sch489796858" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 1:30pm - 2:00pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796859">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796859" value="489796859" data-seq="2281113" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796859');">
                        2:00pm - 2:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796859" id="sch489796859dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796859" id="t_sch489796859" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 2:00pm - 2:30pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796860">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796860" value="489796860" data-seq="2281114" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796860');">
                        2:30pm - 3:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796860" id="sch489796860dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796860" id="t_sch489796860" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 2:30pm - 3:00pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796861">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796861" value="489796861" data-seq="2281115" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796861');">
                        3:00pm - 3:30pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796861" id="sch489796861dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796861" id="t_sch489796861" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 3:00pm - 3:30pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><div class="checkbox">
                      <label for="sch489796862">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="sid[]" id="sch489796862" value="489796862" data-seq="2281116" class="durc" onchange="checkDur('489796862');">
                        3:30pm - 4:00pm
                      </label>
                    </div><input type="hidden" name="dur489796862" id="sch489796862dur" value="30"><input type="hidden" name="t_sch489796862" id="t_sch489796862" value="IVC Library - Room 100E 3:30pm - 4:00pm Friday, February 10, 2017"><a href="#bform" class="sr-only">Skip to registration form</a></fieldset>
```

I do not have an easy way of identifying the checkboxes directly, but a hidden input value has something like "IVC Library - Room 100E 8:00am - 8:30am Friday, February 10, 2017" which I can create. I want to use that value to check the box (but that widget with the value doesn't seem to be a checkbox. Is there any way to get the checkbox to be true instead?

EDIT (Current NodeJS and JQuery code):

```
require("jsdom").env("http://ivc.libcal.com/rooms_acc.php?gid=962&d=2017-02-10&cap=0", function (err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

   var $ = require("jquery")(window);
   $(window).ready(function () {

       var checkbox = $("#roombookingform :input[value='IVC Library - Room 100E 8:00am - 8:30am Friday, February 10, 2017']");
        if (checkbox.length) {
            console.log("Checkbox exists.");
            checkbox.prop('checked', true);
            $('#roombookingform #fname').val("FNAME");
            console.log($('#roombookingform #fname').val());
            $('#roombookingform #lname').val("LNAME");
            console.log($('#roombookingform #lname').val());
            $('#roombookingform #email').val("myemail");
            console.log($('#roombookingform #email').val());
            $('#roombookingform #q1').val("3");
            console.log($('#roombookingform #q1').val());
            $('#roombookingform #q2').val("29292929");
            console.log($('#roombookingform #q2').val());

            console.log("\n\n-------------------\n\n");

            console.log($('#roombookingform #sch489796848').val());
            console.log($('#roombookingform #fname').val());
            console.log($('#roombookingform #lname').val());
            console.log($('#roombookingform #email').val());
            console.log($('#roombookingform #q1').val());
            console.log($('#roombookingform #q2').val());

            $("#roombookingform #s-lc-rm-ac-but").click(function () {
                // do something when button is clicked
                console.log("Button clicked.");
            });          
            $("#roombookingform :button[id='s-lc-rm-ac-but']").click();    
        }

    });
});
```

It doesn't submit either... I'm guessing it's because of the checkbox issue.

I'm looking for a way to use some way other than the id to identify that checkbox because there is no reliable way to keep track of the id.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I've added my current code to it, thanks!